# how to show some pages of a pdf file in a webpage

Tags: c#, pdf, web

I want to display for example just 15 first pages of a PDF file stored in data base,as preview in a web application project coded by C#
how can I do it?is it possible to do it using Ajax toolkit or C# code or should I use componet like Adobe reader or sth else?

Comment: http://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/

Answer (score 0):

With PDF.JS you can render specific page numbers - I'm currenlty using it to embed for an iPad view, its a bit slow though

```
PDFJS.getDocument('helloworld.pdf').then(function(pdf) {
 // Using promise to fetch the page
    pdf.getPage(1).then(function(page) {
    var scale = 1.5;
    var viewport = page.getViewport(scale);

   //
   // Prepare canvas using PDF page dimensions
   //
   var canvas = document.getElementById('the-canvas');
   var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
   canvas.height = viewport.height;
   canvas.width = viewport.width;

   //
   // Render PDF page into canvas context
   //
   var renderContext = {
      canvasContext: context,
      viewport: viewport
   };
    page.render(renderContext);
   });
});
```

Check out the hello world example https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/tree/master/examples/helloworld

Comment: tanx but there are some more question about pdf js?
does it work on everey other explorer such as chrom?

Comment: @thirdDeveloper I'm using PDFObject to work on normal browsers (Chrome, IE etc) then pdfjs for the iPad because PDFObject needed the application/pdf mimetype. My initial experience was that pdf.js didn't seem to work on Chrome but I assumed I was missing a step

Comment: The git example was what I used - it pretty much covers everything needed - https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/tree/master/examples/helloworld